How to prove that $3 \binom{n-3}{2}$-regular graph on $\binom{n}{3}$ vertices has no independent subset on $n+1$ vertices?
We are given a $3 \binom{n-3}{2}$-regular connected graph on $\binom{n}{3}$ vertices. That is, the degree of every vertex is equal to $3 \binom{n-3}{2}$. How to prove this graph has no independent subset on $n+1$ vertices? I mean it is impossible to select $n+1$ vertices in the graph in such a way that any two of them are not connected. I have no idea how to prove it.

Where is this question from ?

@EwanDelanoy there is a classical problem that might be solved via graph theory: suppose we have a set $A={1, ..., n}$ and another one set $B={M_{1}, ..., M_{n+1}}$ where $M_{j}$ are subsets of $A$ such that $|M_{j}|=3$. Prove that there exist $M_{s} \in B$ and $M_{k} \in B$ such that $|M_{s} \cap M_{k}|=1$. This problem is equivalent to the problem in my question

This is false in general. There is a well-known construction of one specific $3\binom {n-3}2$-regular connected graph on $\binom n3$ vertices with no independent set on $n+1$ vertices. Are you sure you have included all the relevant context?

Given the comment a second before mine (which should really have been part of the original post), does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796779/a-constructive-lower-bound-on-ramsey-numbers answer your question?

@MishaLavrov there is $3\binom{n-3}{2}$-regular graph in my question, not $3\binom{n}{2}$-regular

@MishaLavrov yes, I am sure. Tris problem is equivalent to that one I have mentioned in my previous comment. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ subsets of A cardinality $3$ and such a subset intersects with $3\binom{n-3}{2}$ other subsets exactly by one element, so if we are considering a graph on $\binom{n}{3}$ vertices then all the vertices have degree $3\binom{n-3}{2}$ and we have to prove there are no independent subsets on $n+1$ vertices in this graph to prove the claim

Yes, but not every graph on $\binom n3$ vertices where all the vertices have degree $3\binom{n-3}{2}$ arises from your construction. If you want to ask the general question about regular graphs, then I have answered it (in the negative) below. If you instead want to know about the specific graph, then see the older question I linked to.

The claim in the question is false; it is possible for a $3\binom{n-3}2$-regular connected graph on $\binom n3$ vertices to have much larger independent sets.
Suppose that $n \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so that $\binom n3$ is even. Construct a bipartite graph with $N = \frac12 \binom n3$ vertices on each side as follows: call the vertices on one side $x_0, \dots, x_{N-1}$, the vertices on the other side $y_0, \dots, y_{N-1}$, and create edges $x_i y_{i+k\bmod N}$ for $i=0,\dots,N-1$ and $k=0,\dots, 3\binom{n-3}{2}-1$.
The resulting graph is $3\binom{n-3}{2}$-regular, and connected (in particular, there is a Hamiltonian path $y_0x_0y_1x_1y_2x_2\dots y_{N-1}x_{N-1}$), but it has plenty of independent sets of size $n+1$: in fact, $\{x_0, \dots, x_{N-1}\}$ and $\{y_0, \dots, y_{N-1}\}$ are both independent sets of size $N$.

thank you! Cool counterexample
